# the api given below is working with local address but showing error after uploaded in github

Tags: javascript, error-handling

The API given below is working with the local address but showing error after uploaded in Github.

MY CODE:

```
cons = function(){
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()    
}

//GET
cons.prototype.get = function(url,callback){
    this.xhr.open('GET',url,true)
    let self
    self = this.xhr
    this.xhr.onload = function(){
        if(self.status===200){
            callback(null,JSON.parse(self.responseText))
        }
        else{
            callback(`error found ${self.status}`)
        }
    }
    
  
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "baconator-bacon-ipsum.p.rapidapi.com");
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "api-key");
    
    this.xhr.send()
}
```

MY ERROR:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://baconator-bacon-ipsum.p.rapidapi.com/?sentences=0&paras=1&start-with-lorem=0&type=all-meat'
> from origin 'https://nikhildeveloper.github.io' has been blocked by
> CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
> 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is needed to be configured on the back-end side. Your backend needs to allow CORS for glthub domain

The reason that it is working on your local environment is they are both working under same domain which is generally localhost.

Comment: how to allow CORS for github domain in java script?

Comment: again which framework are you using at your backend?